# c# 7.3 ValueTuple - check for default after destructuring

Tags: c#, c#-7.3

I have

```
(string name, int val) f(bool ok) {
   if (!ok) return default;
   return ('John', 5);
}
```

I then do somewhere:

```
var result = f(true);
if (result==default) return false;
var (name, val) = result;
... do something with name & val
```

I find this confusing and overly verbose .. I only create `result` for the default check - I don't need it otherwise ... is there a more elegant way to check for default without using the `result` intermediary variable ?

I can do:

```
var (name, val) = f(true);
if ((name, val)==default) return false;
... do something with name & val
```

but again that's tedious especially if the ValueTuple have lot's of arguments ...

EDIT:

I now realize that the above code is not only verbose but that the general pattern is buggy - you cannot use default as a substitute for an error state with ValueTuples  reason being that for some ValueTuple's - ie (int, int) - it is impossible to tell the default from an otherwise valid value - ie (0, 0) etc ..

Comment: maybe validate and throw in your `f` method, though i am a little confused about the question TBH

Comment: the throw was confusing - edited my question

Comment: If you have lots of arguments in a tuple, there is a good case for not using a tuple, `I only create result for the default check` this line is confusing, do you mean that you only need the result to check if the method worked or not, but then you are using the result further down in code?

Comment: If I didn't need to check for default I wouldn't need the result var

Comment: edited again to try to make it clearer ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```
private (bool ok, string name, int val) F(bool ok) {
    if (!ok) return (false, "", 0);
    return (true, "John", 5);
}

var (ok, name, val) = F(true);
if (!ok) return;
.. continue
```

Answer (score 4):

The language doesn't have a more succinct way to achieve what you want

However, another approach is to use a *Try* Pattern

```
private static bool TryF(bool ok, out (string name, int val) result)
{
   if (!ok)
   {
      result = default;
      return false;
   }
   result =  ("John", 5);
   return true;
}

...


if (!TryF(false, out var result))
   return;

// continue
```

Comment: would be fun if I could do: if (out var (string name, int val)=f(true)) ...

Comment: oh, I would still need to destructure result again after your // continue

Comment: @kofifus you can use the result afterwards, but honestly there is really much you can do apart from what been shown and what you know unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following.

```
var (name,val) = f(true);
if ((name, val) == default)
```

Comment: @kofifus Does the updated answer help to make it easier with many arguements

Comment: @kofifus You could use switch as well, please check updated answer

Comment: pls see my EDIT above, using default to denote errors is buggy

Comment: default of int is 0, you can't distinguish between if its a valid 0 or default 0.  The other solution you can use making it nullable

Answer (score 1):

You could return a nullable tuple. It's slightly more elegant than returning a default tuple, but worse than Michael Randall's TryXXX answer.

```
private static (string name, int val)? F(bool ok) {
    if (!ok) return null;
    return ("John", 5);
}

var result = F(true);
if (result == null)
    return;
var (name, val) = result.Value;
```